# Considering the licence, can I use ADB for other purposes than creating an Android application?

Tags: adb, sdk

When I try to download Android SDK Platform-Tools (with ADB) from the official site (https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) it is required to accept the license that says (among others):

> 3.1 Subject to the terms of the License Agreement, Google grants you a limited, worldwide, royalty-free, non-assignable, non-exclusive, and non-sublicensable license to use the SDK solely to develop applications for compatible implementations of Android.

And to maybe add some context:

> 3.2 You may not use this SDK to develop applications for other platforms (including non-compatible implementations of Android) or to develop another SDK. You are of course free to develop applications for other platforms, including non-compatible implementations of Android, provided that this SDK is not used for that purpose.

The statement "solely to develop applications for compatible implementations of Android" makes me wonder if it's acceptable that I use ADB just to do something on my phone (installing an application, doing a backup or maybe even using Scrcpy) which is not really connected to creation of some new app.

How should I understand this paragraph? Or maybe it's not really about ADB (or other tools), but SDK itself (which I not really or not necessarily use while using ADB)?

I tried finding a way to directly contact Google about it, but they suggested using Stack Overflow (https://developers.google.com/sites/support). I decided to post this question here first, as I think it may be considered off-toppic there though.

Comment: ADB is open source, licensed under Apache 2 license. You can compile it yourself then none of those restrictions do apply.

Comment: Thank You very much for the suggestion! I though about it, but still I think - for example - Scrcpy uses ADB internally. Also, I'm not really sure where can I download the source code from (I tried looking, but the best I found was this I think: https://github.com/themarpe/android-sdk-tools and I'm not sure where's the sources code from and under what license it's distributed).

Comment: For intro see: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/modules/adb/README.md and https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/modules/adb/ Apache notice: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/modules/adb/NOTICE For source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/modules/adb/

Comment: @MorrisonChang, thank You very much for those links and all! I haven't figured out how to compile it yet, but it's nice to know where can I get this source code from and generally find some more about it.

Comment: This is an interesting question.  You may find it beneficial to ask it here: https://law.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket , thank You for the suggestion! For anyone interested: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/85868/considering-the-licence-can-i-use-adb-for-other-purposes-then-creating-an-andro . And I'm glad You like the question, thank You.